# 16.04: Unable to install compass

Tags: ruby

this ubuntu version brings `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`. so all i did to install was the normal process which is `gem install compass` but this installation throws this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160907-12074-v2oz2d.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.14/gem_make.out
```

i tried with installing `ruby-dev` with the command `apt get install ruby-dev` as root but it is not available on this ubuntu for some reason, it throws this error:

```
Package ruby-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ruby-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What command did you use to install ruby-dev and what error messages did you get?  Add the errors of your ruby-dev install attempt to your question.

Comment: @L.D.James i edited the question explaining how

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @L.D.James ubuntu 16.04 x64

Comment: @nosthertus any reason to use `gem` and not `apt`? Disclaimer: not familiar with Ruby, just a hard core Ubuntu user..

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: @SujeetSinha To be honest, i don't have any reason to use `gem`, i just need `compass` for a `node.js` program

Comment: @nosthertus, then you have the answer :) You can also use `sudo apt install ruby-dev`

Comment: @SujeetSinha `ruby-dev` was not available in my available repositories, i had to do the process shown in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `compass` install is failing because of the lack of the ruby-dev installation.

ruby-dev is included in Ubuntu's repository.  You'll have to update your repository to have the full available packages and depends.

Perform these commands to do this:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
$ sudo apt install ruby-dev
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a small point.. Starting Ubuntu 16.04, you can simply use `apt` instead of `apt-get`. A subtle but a welcome change :)

Comment: @SujeetSinha Thanks.  I agree with the welcome change.  The apt has features that are more convenient to use, such as the `search` argument which doesn't require remembering a separate apt command to run.  I updated the answer to include the change.

Comment: Not mentioned here was another dependency I was missing. In addtion to others listed here, libffi-dev must be installed. sudo apt install libffi-dev