# how to proceed installation of ruby compass?

Tags: software-installation, ruby

```
Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.23/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180226-6140-2ex61w.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

Do anyone have same problem?

Comment: Thanks. I have just Already found same topic where it is fully explained: https://askubuntu.com/questions/822023/16-04-unable-to-install-compass

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install ruby-dev first. Try installing that package and then try installing compass again.

> apt-get install ruby-dev